# Event Viewer and Device Manager for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any Event Viewer and Device Manager equivalent applications for Ubuntu (like Windows) so that I can track every task occurring in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't looking for a GUI, the equivalent of Device Manager would be the three ls commands:

```
lshw
lspci
lsusb
```

Note that `lshw` is a superset of `lspci` and `lsusb`, so you can use the [Hardware Lister (lshw-gtk)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lshw-gtk/) GUI.

To view the logs, there is a GUI application called `System Log` usually installed in Ubuntu by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI, system monitor is your friend.

Search for it in the dash. It has all the processes, CPU, Memory and Network usage, and Disk space.

[image]